# Decoding strings on PHP: Data treats UTF-8 Bytes as Windows-1252

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I am getting data from a web API which has a strange encoding. I am using PHP and can't seem to decode input strings. I seem to be having [this problem](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html), which explains what's going but doesn't really help me figure out how to fix it. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Ask your API provider / see their docs to see what kind of encoding they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try analyzing the encoding using something like `mb_detect_encoding()`.

http://www.php.net/mb_detect_encoding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mb_detect_encoding()` to [detect](https://www.php.net/mb_detect_encoding) the encoding of the strings.

If they are not what you are expecting, you can use `mb_convert_encoding()` to [convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to something like UTF-8 or whatever you want.